# A question about the distribution of the log odds ratios in multivariate contingency tables?

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, odds-ratio, contingency-tables

I know that in $2 \times 2$ tables, one may compute the standard error of the log odds ratio by the formula

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{N_{11}} +\frac{1}{N_{12}}+\frac{1}{N_{21}} +\frac{1}{N_{22}}}$$

where the $N_{ij}$s are the counts of the cell of the ith row and jth column. Now, however,I am working with a much larger contingency table now, with four variables. I was wondering then, can I use this formula to compute standard errors of the *conditional* log odds ratios? And by conditional I mean at fixed levels of the other variables.

A search on the internet proved inconclusive so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Four 0/1 binary variables? Or?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos One of these variables has three levels. The others are binary.